# metapost patatoid generator

Tags: luatex, metapost

In order to pimp a little bit all sets representations in my documents I have been searching for how I could generate patatoid and found [this document](https://www.emse.fr/%7Ezimmermann/RAFT/RAFTpapers/Examples/patate.pdf). However I am not really sure how it works and how it is possible to implement it.

Can someone explain this algorithm and outline the implementation in metapost (with lua(la)tex)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question differs from the one linked in a comment both because it is asked for a specific sort of path (the patatoid) and it is explicitly asked for a metapost solution (which does not exist in the linked question).

I interpret the algorithm like this (you can uncomment :

```
\starttext
\startMPpage[offset=1dk]

vardef patatoid(expr w, h) =
    hide(
    numeric maxi,maxd ; maxd := 0 ;
    numeric dist[] ;
    pair tmpp[] ;
    path sq, p ;
    sq := unitsquare xyscaled (w,h) ;
    for i = 0 upto 3:
        tmpp[i] := point (i + uniformdeviate(1)) of sq ;
    endfor ;
    tmpp[4] := tmpp[0] ;
    for i= 0 upto 3 :
        dist[i] := abs(tmpp[i+1] - tmpp[i]) ;
        if (dist[i] > maxd) :
            maxd := dist[i] ;
            maxi := i ;
        fi ;
    endfor ;
    % draw sq ;
    % draw tmpp[0]--tmpp[1]--tmpp[2]--tmpp[3]--cycle ;
    % drawpoints tmpp[0]--tmpp[1]--tmpp[2]--tmpp[3]--cycle withpen pencircle scaled 4 ;
    p := for i = 0 upto maxi : tmpp[i] .. endfor (uniformdeviate(1))[tmpp[maxi],tmpp[maxi+1]] for i = maxi + 1 upto 3: .. tmpp[i] endfor .. cycle ;
    % drawpoints p withcolor darkred ;
    )
    p
enddef ;

draw patatoid(100,75) withpen pencircle scaled 1 ;

\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

In the image below I have uncommented the commented lines, showing the rectangle and the points.

[image: a patatoid]

The file above is complete if you compile with `context`. If you are using metapost in some other environment, you should use the part between `\startMPpage` and `\stopMPpage`.